# Can't create excel file including only specific columns of a pandas DF

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

```
url = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/25th-nujf/rows.csv'
baby_names = pd.read_csv(url)

girls = baby_names[baby_names['Gender'] == 'FEMALE']
boys = baby_names[baby_names['Gender'] == 'MALE']

excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter('Baby_Names.xlsx')

girls.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Girls', index=False)
boys.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Boys', index=False, columns=['Year of Birth', 'Gender', 'Ethnicity'])

excel_file.save()
```

The first sheet contains and should contain all the original columns, while the second only the ones I mentioned. However, this last one still contains all the original columns, still displaying the three additional ones, as if I had never entered the `columns=` parameter.

UPDATE: this format doesn't work either:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Baby_Names.xlsx') as excel_file:
    girls.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Girls', index=False)
    boys.to_excel(excel_file, sheet_name='Boys', index=False, columns=['Year of Birth', 'Gender', 'Ethnicity'])
    excel_file.save()
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: why do you think the columns should be changed? you're filtering on rows.

Comment: because, I only want to use the specified columns in the columns= parameter, which doesn't seem to work even though I'm following instructions from a course